# Nested transform in Gremlin (Titan)

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, titan

I have a graph with two vertexes with a key called 'type'.

Why the following:

```
g.V("type", "language").transform { language_1 ->
  1+1;
}
```

returns:

```
==>2
==>2
```

and the following:

```
g.V("type", "language").transform { language_1 ->
  g.V("type", "language").transform { language_2 ->
    1+1;
  }
}
```

returns:

```
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe, TransformFunctionPipe]
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe, TransformFunctionPipe]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the second example is the String representation of a pipeline. Both of your example queries return pipelines, but when the Gremlin console sees a pipeline returned it automatically reads all the data out of it and displays it. If you wish to use the data returned from a nested pipeline within a larger query as you do in the second query, you must explicitly read the data. Try this:

```
g.V("type", "language").transform { language_1 ->
  g.V("type", "language").transform { language_2 ->
    1+1;
  }.next()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PaulJackson. I tried to do as you say, but after waiting for some minutes it fails with: `Could not process individual retrieval call`.

Comment: This is a funny query the way it is written. The first says "go find Vertexes with type language, and for each of those, return 1+1." The second says "for each language, return a pipeline that set of 2s for each language." (So for three languages you get a 3x3 nested set of 2s.) Make sure the base query g.V("type", "language") is working. Then experiment with either .next() or .next()._() after either of the closing curly braces or both. All combinations return something for me, but I am using my own console.

Comment: Thanls @Paul_Jackson. You point me in the good direction. I'm only using it for a very concrete case, but I never program in Java. You were right about the `g.V("type", "language")` working bad. However, to really iterate four times (2x2), instead of `.next()`, `.iterate()`  must be used. Best regards.